# Representação semântica de frases passivas

Tags: prolog

Alguém sabe como se faz (em Prolog) a representação semântica de uma frase como:

> o Pedro foi beijado pela Ana.

... de modo que a representação semântica seja a mesma da voz ativa:

> a Ana beijou o Pedro.

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Normalmente isso seria representado pelo fato `beijou(ana, pedro)`, em ambos os casos. Você quer converter as frases em linguagem natural para o mesmo formato canônico, tipo usando DCG? Se for isso, posso explicar numa resposta. Caso contrário, favor explicar melhor sua dúvida.

Comment: Obrigado. Já descobri a resposta. Passa pela elevação de quantificadores.